# how to remove warning W1000 Symbol 'AnsiIndexText' is deprecated in delphi 2006

Tags: delphi

how to remove warning W1000 Symbol 'AnsiIndexText' is deprecated in delphi 2006 for below code

```
StartName : string;
case AnsiIndexText(StartName, ['FSB2', 'FSB3', 'FSB4', 'FSB7']) of 0,1,2,3:
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the one from StrUtils unit, not some crafted (and deprecated) by you?

Comment: StrUtils.AnsiIndexText also give same warning

Comment: Move the mouse cursor over the word `AnsiIndexText`, press `Ctrl` key and click with left mouse button. Which file and line does the IDE show you? Add the file name, line number and a copy of that entire line into your question.

Comment: AnsiIndexText does not give a deprecated message for me in 10.1 Berlin. I am surprised that a function would be deprecated then not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `AnsiIndexText` with [`IndexText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.StrUtils.IndexText)

Comment: You do know that `IndexText()` does nothing else than calls `AnsiIndexText()`, do you? So, how can this solve the problem?

Comment: I thought in newer versions it wouldn't any more. I was confused with what was going on between AnsiString and WideString in the first versions that had `string` on `WideChar` internally. Apparently StrUtils has everything on plain `string`, also on recent versions. But I guess `IndexText` may have not been deprecated in this strange version where `AnsiIndexText` is deprecated, since my answer is accepted.